# Asus P8H67-V AHCI Driver issues when installing Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, drivers, ahci

I'm trying to install Windows as a dual-boot on an Asus P8H67-V (Socket 1155) PC running Elementary OS (Debian). 
Here's my configuration:

- Intel Core I5-2500K
- Samsung 840 Pro SSD

  - This previously had Windows 7 x64 installed.
  - I've cleaned it; now I'm trying to install Windows on it from scratch.
- Samsung 850 Evo SSD

  - This is where I have Elementary OS installed.
- Multiple WD Red (≥ 2 TB)
- 2 × Zotac GeForce GTX 660
- BIOS set to AHCI for boot

  - I consider switching back to IDE in BIOS not to be an option.

I'm trying to install Windows by booting from the following devices:

- External DVD/BR Drive using a verified Win7_x64 Disc
  (this has worked on other machines)
- Samsung USB Stick (128 GB, 8 GB Partition for Win10_x64)

I get this error message:

> Load Driver

A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.

Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step

This message appeared for Windows 10 and Windows 7.

The installers boot like a charm, as does Elementary OS.

**I have tried:**

- Using both a USB 3 port and a USB 2 port. No success over here.
- Somehow I was able to boot both devices in IDE Mode –
  still it wouldn't let me install... Same message.
- Assuming that it has something to do with AHCI instead of IDE in SATA Mode inside BIOS Configuration, I downloaded AHCI Drivers from Intel (chipset manufacturer) and ASUS (motherboard manufacturer) but none of them worked. The drivers were shown as applicable for the hardware (Windows 10 Setup), but I was still not able to continue the setup process.

**Question:**

- Is there a possibility to determine which exact driver is missing? The error message is not what I would call conclusive as it does not really state more than "It's not working, I don't know why."
- Is there something I missed? Any other drivers to try? Any preparation for the Samsung 840 needed I missed?

Comment: I've always had to set the BIOS to IDE mode, install the OS, install the AHCI drivers, and then switch the bios to AHCI. At least with Win7. I believe Win10 installed with AHCI support.

Comment: Disabling AHCI does not give me permission to boot from usb / external dvd drive. It also removes both SSDs from boot device lists.

Comment: Also See: [Windows 7 USB install error](http://superuser.com/questions/750520/windows-7-usb-install-error), [ASUS UX31A - A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing](http://superuser.com/questions/826117/asus-ux31a-a-required-cd-dvd-drive-device-driver-is-missing?noredirect=1)

Comment: I’ve thrown this question into a shredder and put the pieces back together in what seems to me to be a more coherent arrangement.  If I mangled the meaning, please fix it.

Comment: add the chipset/AHCI drivers into the Boot.wim. Follow the dup link

Comment: How should that be performed under linux?

Comment: install a Windows 7 ENterprise Trial in a Virtual Machine

Comment: also there is a lib called wimlib which is cross platform tool to manage WIMs: https://wimlib.net/